# How to know the probability of having 0 or 1 object on a series of samples?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am facing a probability problem : I have a certain volume $Vtot$ of water, in which I have $n$ particles. I am aiming at sampling 0 or 1 (no more) particle in every drop (of a volume $Vdrop$).

So I want to know the probability of getting 0 or 1 particle per drop and then estimate which dilution I have to do in order to have best results (P>0.95).

I tried a combinatorics approach but I cannot get through with it since every time I would sample more than 1 particle, chances to get 0 next time would rise, and *vice versa*

Well, any help would be much appreciated, it is certainly a simple problem but I just might have the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that there are many more particles in your volume ($N_p$)than your desired sample size, $n$, so that the number of particles you sample do not affect the subsequent sampling to a significant extent and your sample volume is small compared to the total volume, (i.e, $N_p >> n$ and $V_{tot}>>nV_{drop}$. In that case, you can model the number of particles in your drop $N_d$ as a poisson random variable, with rate parameter $\lambda = \frac{N_p}{V_{tot}}V_{drop}$. Then you can calculate P($N_d=1$) and P($N_d=0$) using this poisson.

Now, if the above assumptoins are not true, then for each drop, we can still model it as a poisson, but the rate parameter will change each sample. The first drop will be modeled the same way, but subseuqent drops will require you to make a branch for each possibility: E.g., P($N_{d1}=0$) [branch 1] and P($N_{d1}=1$) [branch 2]. For each of sbusequent sample,  you will need to do this again, but the number of branches will grow such that if you plan to take $n$ samples, you will have $2^n$ branches at the final stage. Not an appealing calculation (although it can be easily programmed into R or some other language that supports intermediate math functions).